# Spring portlet @ActionMapping usage

Tags: java, spring-mvc, portlet

could please anybody explain, how POST request should be mapped properly ? it is not clear from API documentation.

value should be assigned with the value of the action parameter javax.portlet.action

```
@ActionMapping(value = "addDocOrder")
public void addDocOrder(@ModelAttribute("order").......
```

AND next we have "params" (JAVADOC: The parameters of the mapped request, narrowing the primary mapping.)

```
@ActionMapping(params = "action=addDocOrder")
public void addDocOrder(@ModelAttribute("order").......
```

> > JAVADOC for value() parameter of annotation:  The name of the action,
> >     according to
> >     the Portlet 2.0 "javax.portlet.action"
> >     parameter.  If not specified, the
> >     method will be used as default
> >     handler: i.e. for action requests
> >     where no specific action mapping was
> >     found. Note that all such annotated
> >     action methods only apply within the
> >     @RequestMapping constraints of the
> >     containing handler class.

I absolutely don't get what is the point of the existence of the "value" annotation parameter. it has afaik no sense in being there ...it is meant to be the primary mapping, params the secondary one, but {params = "action=addOrder"}  makes "value" redundant.

PLEASE: Take a look at this issue which is also relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782971/handling-ajax-requests-with-spring-portlet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with your assessment as well. The only real advantage I can see when reading the spec is that some special handling in the  tag was added. Apparently these two are equivalent:

```
<portlet:actionURL>
  <portlet:param name="javax.portlet.action" value="addDocOrder"/>
</portlet:actionURL>

<portlet:actionURL name="addDocOrder" />
```

That is from "PLT.26.2 actionURL Tag" in the spec.

Comment: I'm grateful to spring that they added the support for portlets, but it has very low priority for them. The fact that @ActionMapping isn't mentioned in documentation and bug reports & feature requests that have more votes and are easier to fix then web-mvc resolved ones are unresolved, speaks for itself.

Comment: So I'm a developer on the uPortal project and for Pluto, the reference implementation of the Portlet specifications. We're finishing up uPortal's Portlet 2.0 support and one of the tasks we're going to tackle when we finish that is updates for Spring's portlet support. We have a fairly big list of changes which should really flush out the support and make it more of a first-class MVC framework for portlets. Unfortunately the changes are probably 8 months away from actually getting into Spring.

Comment: hi, I overlooked this comment, good to know somebody skilled in this area :-) I guess you are the author of this https://wiki.jasig.org/display/PLT/AJAX+in+a+Portlet ? I revisited this question because I got stuck with the same issue that you're solving there. I'd very appreciate if you could drop some lines http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782971/handling-ajax-requests-with-spring-portlet  Thank you

Comment: Sure, I can take a look but that question doesn't appear to exist.

Answer (score 1):

javax.portlet.action is the name of the parameter that value() is mapped to. So for a mapping like:

```
@ActionMapping(value = "addDocOrder")
public void addDocOrder(@ModelAttribute("order").......
```

Your request should URL should be built like:

```
<portlet:actionURL>
  <portlet:param name="javax.portlet.action" value="addDocOrder"/>
</portlet:actionURL>
```

Comment: but that doesn't make any sense. This is what "params" annotation parameter is for ( params - The parameters of the mapped request, narrowing the primary mapping.) It means that "value" is the primary mapping. It would have exactly the same function as ( params = "action=addDocOrder" ) what would it be for ?

Comment: It would make sense, if "params" were parameters from the http POST request body (form fields), but this combination is really confusing

Comment: sorry I wanted to say :it wouldn't make sense

Comment: values just provides shorthand for params from my usage so far these two are the same:
@ActionMapping(value = "addDocOrder")
@ActionMapping(params = "javax.portlet.action=addDocOrder")

Comment: I changed the question so it makes better sense