# Pass Param from portlet:actionURL to ActionMapping in Controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, liferay, action

I need to pass an Id inside in foreach loop from my jsp to the controller in order to make a search with this id.
If I use a resourceURL, in the onClick method i can call the function and pass parameters, something like this `onclick="openNews(${contenido.articlePrimKey}); return false">` and in the data: of the function i can send the param to the controller.
I need to replicate this funcionality but with an actionURL.

I've declared de actionURL this way:

```
<portlet:actionURL var="openNews">
    <portlet:param name="action" value="openNews" />
    <portlet:param name="articleID" value="${contenido.articlePrimKey}" />
</portlet:actionURL>
```

The call of the action did this:

```
<a id="tituloContenido" href="${openNews}">${contenido.titulo}</a>
```

And in the controller i try to recover the param this way:

```
@ActionMapping (params = "action=openNews")
    public void openNewsPortada (ActionRequest  request, ActionResponse response, Model model, @RequestParam(value="articleID") long articleId)
```

But im missing the way to link the param fron the `href="${openNews}"` to the actionURL declaration.

In the controller don´t have any parameter.

Thanks

Comment: Is your action method called when you hit that url? I don't think so, because your action name is `openNews` while your method name is `openNewsPortada`.

Comment: Also, either set `<portlet:param name="javax.portlet.action" value="openNews" />` or `<portlet:actionURL var="openNews" name="openNews">`

Comment: The problem seems to be with the mapping of your `actionURL` with Controller's method.

Comment: [***Reference***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585710/spring-portlet-actionmapping-usage)

Comment: The action method is called but LOG.debug("openNewsPortada articleId:  " + articleId); don't print something on the log. My problem is pass the param from the href to the ActionURL and later to the controller. When is a resourceURL instead of ActionURL, from the Ajax in the data:{} you can pass parameters, but from my casuistic i don't know how

Comment: Would you please check if adding portlet namespace value before name of parameter helps? i.e. `@RequestParam(value="PORTLETNAMESPACEPLACEHOLDERarticleID")`